# Showing that a map $F:C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ takes $ C[0,1]$ to itself.

Tags: real-analysis

There was no real way to make the title as descriptive as it needed to be.

> Let $g: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Let $F: C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ be given by $F(f)=h$ where $\displaystyle{h(x) = \int_{0}^{1} g(x,y, f(y))\,dy}$ for $x \in [0,1]$. Show that $F$ maps $C[0,1]$ to itself. Note that $h$ is well-defined.

It's hinted that it may be useful to approach via showing that $F$ is a compact map (i.e., the image under $F$ of a bounded subset is totally bounded). This question also occurs in the chapter on equicontinuity, so I would venture a guess that that is going to play some role.

Any ideas as to how to proceed? Thanks.

EDIT: Since there hasn't been much response, I'm going to post what I'm thinking so far in terms of a proof. Maybe it'll spark some ideas, or the more powerful minds on Math.SE can tell me if I'm headed off in the wrong direction.

> We aim to show that $h:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, so fix $y \in [0,1]$ and $f \in C[0,1]$. Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $x_0 \in [0,1]$. Since $g$ is continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for $x \in [0,1]$,
>
> $0 < \|(x, y, f(y)) - (x_0, y, f(y))\| = |x-y| < \delta.$
>
> Then
>
> $\displaystyle{|h(x) - h(x_0)| = \left|\int_0^1 g(x,y,f(y)) - g(x_0,y,f(y))\,dy \right|}$.
>
> Since $y$ and $f$ are fixed values, we can consider $g$ as a function of only $x$ and thus
>
> $\begin{align*}
> \left|\int_0^1 g(x,y,f(y)) - g(x_0, y, f(y)) \, dy\right| &= \left|y\,g(x,y,f(y)) - y\,g(x_0, y, f(y)) \right| \bigg|_{0}^{1} \\
> &= \left|g(x,y,f(y)) - g(x_0, y, f(y))\right| \\
> &< \varepsilon,
> \end{align*}$
>
> so for every $y$ and $f$, $h$ is continuous at $x_0$ whence it follows that it is continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Should it be $g(x,y,f(y))$ (rather than $g(x,yf(y))$)?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. It should be $g(x,y,f(y))$.

Comment: I'm afraid your proposed proof doesn't make sense to me.  Your first displayed equation doesn't have anything to do with the continuity of $g$.  And in the last paragraph, are you trying to use the fundamental theorem of calculus?  We don't have any information about the antiderivative of $g(x,y,f(y))$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common technique for problems like this, where we must show that a function obtained by integrating out a variable is continuous, is to use sequential continuity and the dominated convergence theorem.

Namely, let $f \in C([0,1])$; we wish to show that $h$ is continuous.  Let $x \in [0,1]$ and $x_n$ a sequence in $[0,1]$ converging to $x$.  We will try to show that  $h(x_n) \to h(x)$.  Define $u_n : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by $u_n(y) = g(x_n, y, f(y))$, and $u(y) = g(x,y,f(y))$, so that $h(x_n) = \int_0^1 u_n(y)\,dy$ and $h(x) = \int_0^1 u(y)\,dy$.  Since $g$ is continuous in $x$, we have $u_n \to u$ pointwise, so if we can apply the dominated convergence theorem we will be done.  Can you come up with an appropriate dominating function?

Comment: That all sounds great up until the dominated convergence theorem. Upon looking it up, it appears to involve Lebesgue measure, which is something we wont be covering for another week or two. So, given that we're really working over the niceness of $\mathbb{R}$, is there a way to realize it for the Riemann integral?

Comment: Okay, so after more research, it seems that the theorem does apply to $\mathbb{R}$ and the Riemann integral. So, since $u_n$ is converging, maybe choose a constant dominating function $v = \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \|u_n\|$?

Comment: @JoeDub: Yes, that would work.  You just have to verify that $v$ is finite.